# What's the proper way of Naming a class?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, classname, bem

Many people name their classes this way: header-menu

I personally prefer header_logo; as its easier to read as well as copy-paste for a lazy coder.

Is there any significant differences in between naming class with "_" or "-" ?

I am really curious and would love to go with the best method; please enlighten me;

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `_` is used to separate element or block modifiers. So it is **not** valid to use with **BEM**.

Valid names for your example:

```
header-menu
headerMenu
```

More related examples:

**Hyphen style:**

```
header-menu -> block
header-menu__logo -> element
header-menu_theme_xmas -> block modifier
header-menu__logo_size_big -> element modifier
```

**camelCase style:**

```
headerMenu -> block
headerMenu__logo -> element
headerMenu_theme_xmas -> block modifier
headerMenu__logo_size_big -> element modifier
```

From the docs:

> **Naming rules** 
>   `block-name__elem-name_mod-name_mod-val`
>
> Names are written in lowercase Latin letters.
>
> Words are separated by a hyphen (-).
>
> The block name defines the namespace for its elements and modifiers.
>
> The element name is separated from the block name by a double
>   underscore (__).
>
> The modifier name is separated from the block or element name by a
>   single underscore (_).
>
> The modifier value is separated from the modifier name by a single
>   underscore (_).
>
> For boolean modifiers, the value is not included in the name.block-name__elem-name_mod-name_mod-val

More info on naming conventions: https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/

Answer (score 0):

There is not proper way, just use whatever css name convention you like. Of course, there are some guidelines that you can follow or just ignore like: BEM, SMACSS and many more.